# Manage UIButtons within SKScene using the storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, sprite-kit

Using XCode and SpriteKit, how can I can I create a new SKScene for my menu screen and manage buttons and labels using the storyboard. I have created a new class called StartScene (subclass of SKScene), but when I create a new view controller w/in the storyboard and change its class, StartScene is not an option.

How can I manage the menu screen using the storyboard?

Note, I created my project from the Single View Application template so there is no .sks file, only a .storyboard.

Comment: You can use UIButtons in your SKScene. How to manage your menu screen using storyboard is too broad of a question.

Comment: How could I add UIButtons to an SKScene using the storyboard then?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create all your buttons in the

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // rest of button code
    [view addSubview:myButton];
```

Using view of SKView being the key here.

If you are in another method which does not have the SKView view, you can do this:

```
-(void)myMethod {
    SKView* view = self.view;
    // create your button
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. Basically, how can I create a new view controller object (of class StartScene), add it to the storyboard, and manage buttons and labels by dragging on to the screen?

Comment: @LuigiMangione - I don't think you can use storyboard to do what you want. You will have to code the above in yourself.